# How to add Python plug-in to Gnu Global

Tags: python, tags, gnu, gnu-global

my gtags verion is gtags - GNU GLOBAL 5.9.2

I downloaded a python plug-in for Gnu Global [here](http://code.google.com/p/python-global-tags/source/checkout)

copy the globalrc.example to ~/.globalrc

copy the script/python_global_tags.py to ~/bin/python_global_tags.py which is in my $PATH

type: "gtags" in a directory of python files

no complain

type: "global -f test.py"

no output

but "global -g" works, I wander if it is just a wrapper of grep

My Question is:

- Is it even possible to write a plugin in python itself?
- Is there a tutorial for configuring the ~/.globalrc, tutoials in [offical site](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) mention so little about that.

Thanks a lot,

gnu global is rising, but still supports so few languages btw

Comment: apparently this question was also posted on the help-global mailing list, and it received one answer there. Here's the link for anyone interested: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-global/2011-04/msg00001.html

Answer (score 9):

Just for those arriving at this page via Google: now GNU Global *does* support Python (and more) via a wonderful Pygments-based plugin:

https://github.com/yoshizow/global-pygments-plugin

Just follow the README, the only note is that in my case gtags produced empty files for big file trees, possibly due to heavy use of symlinks; the solution is to use `find` as advised in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/manual/global.html):

```
find . -name '*.py' >/tmp/list     # make a file set
gtags -f /tmp/list                 # and use it
```

Now one can either search for definitions

```
global -x main     # suppose you have at least one main() somewhere in the code
```

or references

```
global -rsx sys                    # this is likely to list *all* your modules
```

or even search for possible completions for incomplete tags:

```
global -cs OrderedD                # -c: "complete", -s: "non-local references"
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, GNU Global doesn't support Python yet. The homepage says:

> support C, C++, Yacc, Java, PHP4 and assembly. (definition and
>   reference)

And [this post](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-global/2011-04/msg00001.html) basically says we would need to write a plugin in C. Since global is not supported, I reverted back to the good old [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/):

```
ctags -e -R .
```

Works well, but you don't get backreferences. See also [this other question about etags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501040/how-can-i-use-meta-dot-m-in-python-with-emacs).